# Getting all child data/nodes using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am using `ElementTree` to parse some XML nodes.

One of the variants of nodes is of the format:

```
<data_temp>
  0B10FF1E
  <ref target = 'new_data_1'/>
  0C10AABBCC
  <ref target = 'new_data_2'/>
  0f20112233
</data_temp>
<new_data_1>
 1100AABBCCDDEEFFF
</new_data_1>
```

Tf my root refers to say 'tag', and if I fetch data using:

```
root.text
```

I get only `[text data 1]`.

1. How can I fetch all the text data from the tag?
2. How can get all the ref nodes?

Comment: can u place a sample of xml data correctly

Comment: text data is just some hex numbers

Comment: it can be any thing . to test in my end. if u place a sample will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

you can get the ref tags using here `test.xml` is your xml file

```
root = ET.ElementTree(file="test.xml")
tags= root.findall("./tags")
```

Comment: how to get all the text data ?

Comment: @Dexter is your xml is in correct format.please provide a sample of correct format.